# array_splice behavior in PHP 4.x

Tags: php, migration, php4

I'm in the process of migrating an old piece of code to PHP 8.1 from (hold on to your hat...) PHP 4.2!

However I did make significate progress.
I ran in to the following statement

```php
if ($arr[$key]) {
    array_splice($arr[$key]);
}
```

var_dump shows

```php
$key = 'a';
$arr = ['a' => 1];
```

Obviously this breaks on 8.1 for 2 reasons

1. int is passed as an array.
2. offset is ignored.

I'm having trouble under standing what would have been the behavior of this code under PHP 4.2
Looking at the 4.x documentation of `array_splice` does not explain.

Thank's

Comment: You can run PHP4 here, https://3v4l.org/RF0Ng#v4.3.0. Without values hard to tell though

Comment: OMG thank you, this will help me tremendous. I added values https://3v4l.org/YAVEr#v4.3.0
it errors out `Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_splice() in /in/YAVEr on line 6`
So I guess if `display_errors` was 0 then it simply would ignore this line?

Comment: Seems like it. This is a version behind yours. Looks like https://onlinephp.io/ could be used for 4.2 testing.

Comment: Yes, whatever this line was _intended_ to do, it _actually_ does nothing other than emit a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It emits a warning so it would simply skip this line and continue execution

MIgrated code looks like this

```php
if ($arr[$key] && is_array($arr[$key])) {
    array_splice($arr[$key], 0);
}
```